# How to async pipe an observable in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a service that has some asynchronous stuff to do, how can I postpone a data binding render until the service has done its asynchronous work?

```
this.sessionService.onSessionChange().subscribe(function(session) {
    console.log(session);
    self.user = session.user;
});
```

Service:

```
onSessionChange(): Observable<Session> {
    return this.sessionObservable.asObservable();
}
```

The user is undefined because the session isn't ready yet:

```
<h4>Hi {{user.name}}.</h4>
```

How can I use a pipe with my onSessionChange observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this way too using **`safe navigation operator`**,

```
<h4>Hi {{user?.name}}.</h4>
```

Answer (score 3):

In Angular4, a common idiom is to use the new `as` keyword as follows:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="session$ | async as session">
                                 <!-- ^^^^^^^^^^  "as" keyword -->
  <h4>Hi {{session.user.name}}</h4>
</ng-container>
```

This is even more useful if you are going to use `session` in more than one place in your template.

`<ng-container>` is a place to hang `*ngIf` or `*ngFor` without adding more nodes to the DOM.

Comment: This isn't working, it is not displaying. Do I have to modify anything else?

Comment: I did get it working with a Promise but I want to use an observable

Comment: A possible downside to this approach is that anything in `ng-container` wont appear until `session$` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sajeetharan answered, you can use `safe navigation operator` to avoid undefined error thrown from template.

Just as you stated at your question's header, you can use `Async Pipe` to subscribe/unsubscribe to Observable automatically.

Step1: expose the Observable at your component:

```
// expose Observable in order to access at template
user$: any;
constructor(private sessionService: SessionService) {
  this.user$ = this.sessionService.onSessionChange();
}
```

Step2: use `Async Pipe` at your template to subscribe to the created Observable

```
<h4>Hi {{(user$ | async)?.user.name}}.</h4>
```

Working **[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/6UkTyo7jbpuvJvEtAdkJ?p=preview)**

Comment: is there any reason I should use an async pipe rather than the safe navigation operator?

Comment: @el_pup_le they don't have any conflicts. But by using `async pipe`, you don't need to unsubscribe from the observable at `ngOnDestroy` to prevent from memory leak. This is because `async pipe` will do it automatically for you.

Comment: The `?` following `(user$ | async)` is unnecessary.

Comment: @torazaburo can you explain why? I was thinking `user` is not belong to `(user$ | async)` until response is back.

Comment: @Pengyy could you explain about `(user$ | async)?.user.name`  what I understood is `(user$ | async)` could have the complete session  if this is right  what is the use of safe navigator operator ?

Comment: @k11k2 `user` field is not belong to `(user$ | async)` until response is back. `safe navigator operator` here is for preventing error about `can not find user from null`.

Comment: @Pengyy if user field is not belong to it then  `(user$ | async).user.name` would be enough I think. In case there is no data (user$ completely empty)  safe navigator operator would help along with async.

Comment: @k11k2 you can just confirm by removing `?`. here is what happened. https://plnkr.co/edit/auVjlFt1fkJSWw9k3bmz?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pluck` operator to have an async property:

At the component:

```
this.userName$ = this.sessionService.onSessionChange().pluck('user', 'name')
```

At the template:

```
<h4>{{ userName$ | async }}</h4>
```